# How to change page in ViewPager Android?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, material-design, android-support-library

I am using View Pager in my App.  I need to trigger page change every 1 min. I know that if user swipes, page change happens. But if we have to trigger it, is there any API for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to change page in ViewPager Android?

Use [ViewPager.setCurrentItem(int item)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setCurrentItem(int,%20boolean)) for changing ViewPager pages programmatically.

Where `item` is index of Page which want to set as current item in ViewPager.

Answer (score 1):

```
private int mInterval = 5000; // 5 seconds by default, can be changed later
  private Handler mHandler;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    ...
    mHandler = new Handler();
    startRepeatingTask();
  }

  Runnable mStatusChecker = new Runnable() {
    @Override 
    public void run() {
      updatePage(); //this function can change value of mInterval.
      mHandler.postDelayed(mStatusChecker, mInterval);
    }
  };

  void startRepeatingTask() {
    mStatusChecker.run(); 
  }

  void stopRepeatingTask() {
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mStatusChecker);
  }
private void updatePage(){
 viewPager.setCurrentItem(pageno)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.post(new Updater());

class Updater implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(mViewPager.getCurrentItem() + 1);
        if (mViewPager.getAdapter().getCount() - 1 > mViewPager.getCurrentItem()){
            handler.postDelayed(new Updater, 60000);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CountDownTimer` do this easily.Change the page after every 60sec using below example

```
   class MyTimer extends CountDownTimer{

         public MyTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
             super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
         }

         @Override
         public void onTick(long l) {

         }

         @Override
         public void onFinish() {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem() + 1);
            myTimer.start();
         }

    MyTimer myTimer = new MyTimer(1000*60, 1000);
    myTimer.start();
```